Searching for "part" of a word/line in Notepad++
I have a large list of movies I have the filename in a text doc. I'd like to be able to type part of a name of a movie to search and see if I have that movie. The problem is, some movies are names Title.extension, some are named firstword of title.nextword of title. nex word of title.resolution.audiocodec.extension, etc.
So it could be the filename is The Last Airbender.MKV, but it could also be Last Airbender, The.MKV or it might be the.last.airbender.1080p.AAC.MP4 etc.
Searching for just bender or *bender* like I would do in windows explorer doesn't seem to work. is there a way to do a similar search in Notepad++?

In the Notepad++ Find window, make sure that the following options are set:

Match whole word only: Unchecked
Match case: Unchecked
In selection: Unchecked (unless searching selected text)
Search Mode - Normal checked

This will allow for searches where the search word will match inside of other words, even if case is different.
Example of searching part of OP's question for "bender" with all results:

